Cannot get nginx Ingress with regexp for multiple path working
I want that all request to myadress.com/momo-store go to frontend and all others to myadress.com/orders or /categories to backend services, but that does not work
My Ingress so far looks like this
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ .Chart.Name }}
annotations:
  nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: "nginx"
  rules:
  - host: "{{ .Values.fqdn }}"
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /momo-store
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: frontend
            port:
              number: 8080
      - path: /(products|categories|orders|auth/whoami)
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: backend
            port:
              number: 8081


For all requests other that /momo-store I am getting 404
Do not know if it is importand, but I am using ingress from minikube

Using pathType: ImplementationSpecific, it may not work as expected. Instead, consider using pathType: Prefix for all paths. Kindly validate this which may help you.

Hi, thank you, I had Prefix at the beginning, but it complains that this type is not compatible with "use-regex"
